# Endpoints in associated accounts call

Tags: feature-request

> **Slightly related:**
>   [Add reputation and site URL to 1.1 associated accounts](https://stackapps.com/questions/2009/add-reputation-and-site-url-to-1-1-associated-accounts)

Currently, the only way to identify a site from the [associated accounts route](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/stackauth-methods/user-associations) is by its **name**. This is pretty error-prone and useless if you are trying to do something more than just **display** the associated sites, like, for example, displaying the user's profile on that site.

Also, say I cached all the sites using the `/sites` method (which, btw, needs a way to get **all** the sites for caching purposes so I don't have to make more than one call). The only way to map an associated site to one in my cache is, again, **by its name**, which is, well, horrible.

Because of this, supplying the endpoint of the site (it can even replace the name if you ask me) is pretty necessary.

I understand that I can "just use 1.0", but that's not a nice / correct solution either.

Comment: Thank you for this question!! I doubt you'll get it, this API is very focused on "how it should be done" not what would make life easier for developers.